# Continuous validation of maven dependencies on multi-module project

Tags: java, maven, build, continuous-integration, multi-module

I have a multi-module web-application maven project.

Iterating over list of dependencies of each module (`depndencies:list`) - it's easy to see dependencies conflicts - but is there a plugin that produces conflicts report so I can run it in my CI server as build validation?

  **Examples for conflicts:**
- Circular dependencies.
- Same dependency with different version on different sub-modules

Comment: What kind of conflicts would you like to see ?

Comment: Circular dependencies, different versions of dependencies in different sub-modules...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah...so best for such things is the [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) which contains such rules to enforce things like this and break the build if someone is doing something wrong..

To prevent circular dependencies you should use the `banCircularDependencies` rule from the [extra-enforcer-rules](http://mojo.codehaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/banCircularDependencies.html)

To prevent different versions in sub modules you can use the [dependencyConvergence](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/dependencyConvergence.html) rule which is exactly for such purposes.

The [requireUpperBoundDeps](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireUpperBoundDeps.html) might also be interesting for you.